# QML/C++ Websockets

Tags: qt, websocket, qml

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-qmlwebsocketserver-example.html

can somebody tell me how can I use this for lets say a real-time game? Do I have to compile it and upload it on a server? And then? Is this code even production ready?

Please help, I have no idea and I already watched so many videos about websockets. Some kind of tutorial for a real use of this code on a server would be nice :D.

Comment: Qt has websocket support since Qt 5.3(it's builtin, you don't need to download and build it). In general you have client and server items. See it [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-qmlmodule.html). The usage clearly shows in following example: [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-qmlwebsocketserver-example.html)

Comment: I complety understand that demo. But I need to upload something on my server? What do I upload and how? And do I have to configure something else?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do

Comment: :) I want to make a real time game. I have lets say a XAMPP server and this code from the Qt documentation. How can I make it work that I can make a connection from an qml application to the xampp server with this Qt/qml backend?

Comment: Qt/QML with WebSocket on frontend and anything (php or whatever) supports creating websocket service listening on the server.

Comment: why not something compiled from qt listening on the server?

Comment: Why not, if you have Qt installed on the server. But I think QML is not the best choice as a server script.

Comment: I thought compile to an .exe and upload it on the server

Comment: If you have a windows server and the permissions to run an exe, you can do that. But as you need no frontend you don't need a framework that is mainly for frontends. Of course you can use the QT-Libraries for all kind of stuff, but QML is unlikely to be needed on your server. You can use Qt/QML for your client and __*anything*__ that enables you to create a webserver that performs the - well - server stuff on the server side. You could even write it in `LISP` or  `Shakespear` if you are up to.

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly the example you're looking for: [Simple Chat example (how to use QWebSocket and QWebSocketServer)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-simplechat-example.html)

If you want to use this in a production environment, you do want to enable SSL on the server - look at the [SSL Echo Server Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-sslechoserver-example.html)

Of course, in order to be able to use a Qt program as a game server you'll have to find a way to store data (via [QSqlDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html) or other) and more over, you'll need a way to authenticate and authorize users (could be done via the [Qt Network Authorization API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetworkauth-index.html) + an OAuth service provider).

Anyway, if your aim is to develop a game **you should definitely checkout [V-Play's SDK](https://v-play.net/)** since it really looks like a very effective way of developing QML based games.

Hope this helps you find what you need !

D

[Edit] PS: Oh and don't forget to check Qt's official forum, a lot of topics are treated there : https://forum.qt.io/